# Using DISTINCT in LEFT JOIN in mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join

Here is my query

```
SELECT agent.agtname AS `agent_name`, agent.id as `agent_id`, applicant.* 
FROM `applicant` 
LEFT JOIN agent ON agent.id = applicant.agtid 
WHERE agent.branchid ='".$branch_id."' 
AND applicant.appt_status LIKE '%SENT%' 
AND DATE(`modifiedon`) = CURDATE()
```

I don't need the repeated agent_name as well as agent_id..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include sample data.  To remove duplicates will likely either mean doing an aggregation of some sort over the columns other than `agent_name` and `agent_id`, or changing your query strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's try this.
it will work...

```
SELECT agent.agtname as agent_name,agent.id as agent_id, applicant.* FROM applicant LEFT JOIN agent ON agent.id = applicant.agtid WHERE agent.branchid ='".$branch_id."' AND applicant.appt_status LIKE '%SENT%' AND DATE(modifiedon) = CURDATE() GROUP BY agent.agtname
```

Comment: thank you soo much bro..u did it simply..actually i was expecting DISTINCT method..I am having little confustion in distinct method..